# Column type of "Hyperlink or Picture"not being crawled?

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, crawled-property

I have a custom column in my document library of type:
Hyperlink or Picture

I go into Library Settings and click Reindex Document Library.  I'm on SharePoint Online and have waited overnight, yet I can't find this column under Crawled Properties.

In the past I have successfully added and mapped Managed Metadata Columns and Text Columns.  In searching for a hyperlink column in search Schema how should I be searching?

Thanks!

EDIT-----------------------------------
I just created a new text column and added the hyperlinks.  This column was crawled and appeared in Crawled Properties almost immediately.  Something is different with Column types that are hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

Good day!

I just did a check and I see that hyperlink columns were indeed being crawled as crawled properties.

Could it be that the Internal Name of the column does not match what you are searching for in the search application. If a column is created with spaces in its name, SharePoint will assign strange character combinations to the internatal name. I find the easiest way to find the Internal name of the column is to go to the list / library settings, click on the desired column, and look at the URL of the page in CHROME.

I would suggest checking the internal name of the column and see if matches what you searched for in the central search. Look at the screenshots I posted below.

Finding the internal name of the column...

[image]

Finding it in the central search...

[image]